# vim: find a line containing pattern that is not in the neighbouring lines

Tags: vim

I want to find a way to show all the lines that contain certain pattern,
but it's neighbouring(previous, next) lines doesn't.

e.g: let's say pattern is word "PATTERN"

1.#########################

2.#########PATTERN#########

3.##############################

then 2nd line is valid and shown.

BUT

1.#########################

2.#########PATTERN#########

3.#########PATTERN#########

4.##############################

then 2nd and 3rd lines are not valid, therefore won't show

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'd want to use regex capture groups, as follows:

```
/\v%(PATTERN.*\n.*)@<!(PATTERN)%(.*\n.*\1)@!
```

[image: Example]

This might look scary, but it's actually quite simple:

1. `\v` is used to enable *"very magic"* regex (avoids the usage of backslashes for most special characters)
2. `PATTERN.*\n.*` is `PATTERN`, followed by anything, a newline, and anything again
3. `(...)@<!` is the pattern for negative look-behind: it means that we **don't want** what's between the braces to exist. So in our case, all of step `2` shouldn't exist
4. `(PATTERN)` This is our actual word, this should exist! We capture it with braces for future usage
5. `.*\n.*\1` is anything, a newline, anything again, and our captured group (see step `4`)
6. `%(...)@!` is a negative look-ahead, as before, we don't want what's between the braces to exist.

So basically, we want `PATTERN`, which is:

- not preceded by a line containing `PATTERN`
- not succeeded by a line containing `PATTERN`